# Does a subclass take more memory than a superclass

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, heap-memory

Does an object initiated with class B which inherits class A take up more memory in the heap than an object initiated with class A.  Below are two scenarios I was considering:

Scenario 1:

```
class A {
  String name;
}

class B extends A {

}
```

Scenario 2:

```
class A {
  String name;
}

class B extends A {
  int age;
}
```

Comment: Are the classes in question actually this simple?

Comment: Maybe. As a java developer you aren't responsible for memory management.

Comment: I don't think there would be any discernible difference, or, at least not one you should be wary of. Methods (as far as I know?) are referenced, by, well, reference, so they would be shared across all instances of the same class (not so sure about inheritance). Fields might be a cause for concern but really if this is something you worry about in terms of performance perhaps java isn't the language for you :^)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at your examples:

- Scenario #1: there should be no difference in size between an instance of `A` and an instance of `B`
- Scenario #2: an instance of `B` *may* occupy more space than an instance of `A`, but it depends on word alignment, and on whether you are running a 32 or 64 bit JVM and/or have "compressed oops" enabled.  In short, the answer is JVM specific.

In general subclassing *per se* does not entail extra memory per instance, but extra fields *may* do, depending on how the JVM lays out the instance fields in a heap node.

But I concur with the comments.  A Java application programmer shouldn't need to concern him / herself with this kind of thing.  The difference in size is likely to be so small as to be irrelevant ... unless you have to create *millions* of these objects.  And even then, there are probably more important things to worry about.